# Initializing a pointer to point to a character in a string using the pointer pointing to the string

Tags: c++

```
int isPurePalindrome(const char *sentence){ 
int i;     
if (sentence="")     
return 0; 
char *begin; char *end; i=strlen(sentence);//i is now the length of sentence string 
*begin= &sentence(0); 
*end=&sentence[i-1];
```

I'm using dev c++. Im trying to initialize pointer "begin" to point to the first character in the string "sentence", but it keeps giving me an error that "assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast." 
"*sentence" points to the string entered by the user in the main. ispalindrome is a function im writing. its suppose to return a 0 if the sentence entered in main is a NULL.

Comment: basically you wont be able to compile this code.compiler complaints for string compare. and after removing that the code should be compiled under `C99` standard

Answer (score 3):

There are a few issues with your code:

```
if (sentence="") return 0;
```

should be

```
if (strcmp(sentence,"")==0) return 0;
```

---

```
char *begin; char *end;
```

should be

```
const char *begin; const char *end;
```

---

```
*begin= &sentence(0);
```

should be

```
begin = &sentence[0];
```

---

```
*end=&sentence[i-1];
```

should be

```
end = &sentence[i-1];
```

Comment: maybe you could also mention about the mixed declaration and the body wrt standards

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of problems in your code, but the one causing that error message is that you're dereferencing when you don't need to be.  You want:

```
begin = &sentence[0];
end = &sentence[i-1];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
begin = &sentence[0];
end = &sentence[i - 1];
```

This will solve your problem..

Answer (score -1):

You should write `[]` insted of `()` in

```
 *begin= &sentence(0);
```

you should caste sentence to (char*) before assigning it to begin and end.

```
*begin =  ((char*)sentence)[0];

*end =  ((char*)sentence)[i -1];
```

Comment: Casting only hides the bug instead of fixing it